# How to serialize object with shared_ptr member using boost

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization

There are abstract `I1` and derived `C1`.

There are abstract `I2` and derived `C2`.

`I1` have `shared_ptr<I2>`. How can I make them serializable using boost serializaton? I am attemtping do it, but my application get exception.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct I1
{
    I1() {}
    virtual ~I1() = 0 {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
    }
};

struct C1 : I1
{
    virtual ~C1() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<I1>(*this);
    }
};

struct I2
{
    virtual ~I2() = 0 {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & p;
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<I1> p;
};

struct C2 : I2
{
    C2() { p = boost::shared_ptr<I1>(new C1); }
    virtual ~C2() { }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<I2>(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    C2 c2;

    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss(s);

    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa.register_type<I1>();
    oa.register_type<C1>();
    oa.register_type<I2>();
    oa.register_type<C2>();

    oa << c2;

    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ss);
    //ia.register_type<I1>(); // cannot instantiate abstract class
    ia.register_type<C1>();
    //ia.register_type<I2>(); // cannot instantiate abstract class
    ia.register_type<C2>();

    ia >> c2;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us which compiler accepts the `=0 {}` syntax? I know it exists but I don't know of a compiler that accepts this input

Comment: Interestingly enough, your code runs fine on gcc 4.8.1 on Linux (well, apart from the `=0 {}` syntax).

Comment: Can you try run this code using msvc please?

Comment: @Ufx, I just did that. You can see exactly what I used and the output in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boost serialization documentation says [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export) interesting things about `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT`:

> ... BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT ...
>
> Hence, the need for export is implied by the usage of a derived class that is manipulated via a pointer or reference to its base class.

Your `p` pointer does exactly that. Adding these macros to your code also gets rid of the ugly explicit `register_type()` calls from your main, which is also nice :)

So, this code seems to compile and work in VS2014:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

struct I1
{
    I1() {}
    virtual ~I1() = 0 {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(I1)

struct C1 : I1
{
    virtual ~C1() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<I1>(*this);
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(C1)

struct I2
{
    virtual ~I2() = 0 {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & p;
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<I1> p;
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(I2)

struct C2 : I2
{
    C2() { p = boost::shared_ptr<I1>(new C1); }
    virtual ~C2() { }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<I2>(*this);
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(C2)

int main()
{
    C2 c2;

    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss(s);

    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa << c2;

    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ss);
    ia >> c2;
}
```

It is interesting, though, that the statement from Boost docs is obviously not true for all compilers, and lots of code examples on the internets just don't work in VS2014.

Comment: I actually installed VS2014 in a virtual machine to try this, because serializing shared pointers this way simply has to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(I1)
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(I2)
```

As per the documentation http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#abstract

**UPDATE**

I've just verified with VS2013RTM and Boost 1_55, it JustWorks(TM), I've

- removed the type registrations for abstract bases (they can never be *concretely* loaded from the archive anyways)
- added

  ```
  #pragma warning(disable: 4244)
  #include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
  ```

  at the top of the file to silence known chatty warnings

Code compiled and runs without error. For good style, you should probably

- serialize c2 through a pointer (stack variables can [subtly derail object tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking))

Here's the full code I ended up with:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4244)
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct I1
{
    I1() {}
    virtual ~I1() = 0 {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
    }
};

struct C1 : I1
{
    virtual ~C1() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<I1>(*this);
    }
};

struct I2
{
    virtual ~I2() = 0 {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & p;
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<I1> p;
};

struct C2 : I2
{
    C2() { p = boost::shared_ptr<I1>(new C1); }
    virtual ~C2() { }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<I2>(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<I2> c2(new C2);

    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss(s);

    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa.register_type<C1>();
    oa.register_type<C2>();

    oa << c2;
    std::cout << "Serialized form: '" << ss.str() << "'\n";

    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
    ia.register_type<C1>();
    ia.register_type<C2>();

    ia >> c2;
}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Where are they need to be added?

Comment: I'd just add them immediately after the declarations of the interface classes

Comment: @Ufx For what it's worth, I've tested it on VS2013 now - I didn't have access to Windows the other time. Perhaps you should try it in an isolated, fresh, console application to rule out that there's something wrong in the rest of the project/build settings.

Comment: I have just replaced all except main function (and headers) and it still crashed. martin_pr's solusion doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't supposed to register your pure virtual classes on the output archive either.

Alternatively, you can use [export](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export). After defining your classes, replace the rest of your code with this:

```
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(C1)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(C2)

int main()
{
    C2 c2;

    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss(s);

    {
       boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
       oa << c2;
    }

    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ss);
    ia >> c2;
}
```

I put the output archive into a separate block. I think it most likely works without it but I want to be sure that everything is flushed (via going out of scope).

Comment: Didn't help for me. Does it work for you? I use MSVC12.

Comment: It does work for me on clang and gcc. Did you try both approaches (deleting register_type for abstract classes, replacing main with above code)? And what errors, same one?

Comment: I think error is a same one. archive_exception(archive_exception::unregistered_class) "unregistered class". Call stack: http://pastebin.com/wU7ARa4F